# How to use USB Keyboard and USB Mouse In Android Tablet Simultaneously

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, tablet, usb-peripherals, external-keyboard

My Android Tablet is having one Standard USB port and One Micro USB port I use Mini for 3G Dongle..... Tablet is not having Bluetooth. I want to know is it possible to connect mouse and keyboard from one standard USB port in Tablet ... Like we use headphone...

I am using this tablet http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2012/12/bsnl-701c-penta-tablet-3gplay-store-not.html

Comment: Please clarify 'mini'.  Do you use **standard** or **micro** USB for 3G dongle?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a cable hub.

You should be able to find one that takes only one USB port of device, and provides 2 (or 3) USB ports.

for example:
[cable hub ,USB 2.0 3-port HUB with Micro 5P](http://dtech.en.alibaba.com/product/516900001-50168636/cable_hub_USB_2_0_3_port_HUB_with_Micro_5P.html) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your tablet supports a USB hub, you might try connecting both devices to a hub and then connecting that hub to your tablet.

Comment: Please use standard english

Comment: How to check if it supports hub or not :/ its Penta Tab 701c you search its spec on net